# 24 channel PWM IC

Tags: led, mosfet, pwm

I wan't to drive 8 RGB LED stripes (8 stripes * 3 colors per stripe = 24 channels) with PWM. Each output is driven with a logical level MOSFET. The stripes already have a resistor. I have looked at the TLC5940 and the TLC5942, but a forum post says, you have to set "BLANK" to ground to repeat each PWM cycle, and the ICs are a bit too "big" for this project. Is there a "simple" 24 channel PWM IC out there (SPI or I2C preferred)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLC5952 don't have this bug, and it's cheaper than TLC5942 in Farnell.

Comment: You are right, but i solved the problem otherwise (i used a XC5972XL CPLD)

Comment: @TEAM-ALPHA i can't find this part - XC5972XL, would you mind sharing the exact number?

Comment: @miceuz i'm verry sorry, i have written it wrong. True name is XC9572XL, it's a CPLD by Xilinx.

Comment: @TEAM-ALPHA how many PWM channels have you managed to cram into this CPLD? any chance of sharing your verilog code for that?

Comment: @miceuz i haven't done it in verilog, the ISE webpack supports "drawing" the program with a digital schematic. The CPLD was too small for all channels, because i wanted a 8 bit shift register as the comparison value for each channel. ~18-20 channels will fit, but if you write it in verilog results may be better.